# How do i get rid of extra space in the front and back of a array when select certain number to print

Tags: javascript

I want to return an array containing all the elements of the array located at the given key that are equal to ten. It should print out `[10, 10]` but the result of my code is `[ 10, 10 ]` with extra space in the front and back or my code is just wrong.

```
var obj = {
    key: [1000, 10, 50, 10],
    key2: [],
    key3: "abc"
};

function isValid(obj, key) {
    var result = []; 
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("key") ||
        !Array.isArray(obj[key]) ||
        obj[key].length === 0) {
            return []; //return empty array if those condition meet.
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
            if (obj[key][i] === 10) {
                result.push(obj[key][i]); //push the 10 to result empty array.
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

var output = isValid(obj, 'key');
console.log(output); // --> should print out [10, 10]
```

Comment: can't reproduce, your code outputs `[10, 10]` as expected

Comment: that's weird, or is there a better way to print out the same result?

Comment: you are using `console.log`. the appearance is vendor specific. for getting a stable result, you yould use `JSON.stringify` and serialize a string of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with your browser. Space seperating contents in an array automatically removed when you iterate through it. Some browsers add a space between each entry for visual improvement. As you are using a number array, the space will not affect your normal code execution.